# Bitcoin sendfrom not returning any errors

Tags: php, bitcoin

I am trying to validate bitcoin engine respond once executing with correct amount within the account balance and correct wallet I am getting transaction ID, but if I enter amount too much and fake wallet I am not receiving any error in return just a blank page with html, head and body elements. Is there is any debug mode or what I can do to  receive any response?

```
$message = ($bitcoin->sendfrom($mywallet,$to_wallet,$wammount));
```

I am using jsonRPCClient to connect with bitcoin engine.

however when I do that in console using RPC commands

I am getting this : Account has insufficient funds (code -6)

code for redirection

```
if ($message !== '') {
ob_start(); 
header("Location: mywallet.php?error=done");
die();

} else { 


ob_start(); 
header("Location: mywallet.php?error=true");
die();


    }
```

**Update** Yes correct I will more ob_start(); above, thing is that once trying (try,catch) event I am getting blank page upon SUCCESS (so not transaction ID like with normal way I am doing I am getting back transaction ID) upon FAIL I am getting Unable to connect to Bitcoin Server. What I just need sounds very simple, how do I verified that transaction is SUCCESSFUL or FAIL, SUCCESSFUL -> I got ID in return, FAIL -> I have got Error in return. SO I can divert users to right places on the page after form is submitted. Actualy I am doing is withdraw funds form, where user inserts amount and his wallet to get funds back from bitcoin account to his private account. Hope this will helps to understand.

**UPDATE 2** I have changed construction for that and seems to is working very well, basically is looking for "Unable" word as transaction ID doesn't have that word and other exception I am getting is "Unable to connect to server..." Thank you for guiding me. Any feedback ?

```
try {
       $message = ($bitcoin->sendfrom($mywallet,$to_wallet,$wammount));
      }
catch (Exception $e) {
       $e->getMessage();

}
// exit;

if (!strpos($e,'Unable') !== false){

header("Location: mywallet.php?error=done");
die();

} else { 


header("Location: mywallet.php?error=true");
die();


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What bitcoin php library are you using?  Looks like maybe [this one?](https://github.com/mikegogulski/bitcoin-php)

If that's the case, it doesn't return an error message, it [throws BitCoinClientException](http://code.gogulski.com/bitcoin-php/class_bitcoin_client.html#ac0a7d86e63a8e1efe8036b0a1bcc62b7)

So you need something like

```
  try {
       $message = ($bitcoin->sendfrom($mywallet,$to_wallet,$wammount));
       }
  catch (Exception $e) {
       echo $e->getMessage();
   }
```

**Updating**
The ob_start seems superfluous because you don't output anything before the header location.  Unless you have output something before you've reached this point in which case you can't send a header.  So you'd need to move the ob_start up towards the top of the script before any output.

Also you aren't sending message to the wallet.php script. Or are you done with it at that point?

---

**RE: update 2**
One thing I might add is the possibility of some other exception message occuring we haven't thought of yet that doesn't contain the "Unable." I'd do something more like:

```php
$errorOccured = false;
try {
       $message = ($bitcoin->sendfrom($mywallet,$to_wallet,$wammount));
      }
catch (Exception $e) {
       $errrorMessage = $e->getMessage();
       $errorOccured = true;

}

if (!$errorOccured) {
   ...
 }
else {
header("Location: mywallet.php?error=true&errormsg=" . $errorMessage);
...
}
```

This would require modifying mywallet.php to accept `$errorMessage` as an additional GET parameter so you can send it back to the user.  Might be nice to additionally use another parameter for sending `$message` on success which would contain the transaction ID.